# How to access a Button's ValidationGroup property

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to access the ValidationGroup value of a button in a javascript function.
The button is part of a nested grid.  I set the ValidationGroup value during the RowDataBound event for the button and the Dropdown controls.  Shown below:

```
protected void UserGroupGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(UserGroupGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);
                GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GroupMemberGridView");
                populateGroupMemberGrid(tgvGroupMember, tiGroupID);

                //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
                Control tFooterControls = CommonMethods.getFooterControls(tgvGroupMember);                
                DropDownList tddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName") as DropDownList;
                m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleGroupMembers(m_strUserID, tiGroupID);
                DataTable tdtAllGroupMembers = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
                tddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllGroupMembers;
                tddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberName"].ToString();
                tddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = tdtAllGroupMembers.Columns["MemberID"].ToString();
                tddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
                tddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));//This is needed for the jquery-chosen dropdown to add data-holder text
                tddlRecipientNames.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();

                Button tbtnAdd = tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvAddButton") as Button;
                tbtnAdd.ValidationGroup = "DDLVal_" + tiGroupID.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

This is the markup for the Dropdown and Button:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0"                                         ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="gridActionbutton" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return Validate(this);" >
</asp:Button>
```

When the button is clicked, I call the client-side function, Validate(this).
This is the Validate function:

```
function Validate(ClientID) {
  valgroup = ClientID.Validators[0].validationGroup;
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM.  valgroup is null?
  alert(valgroup);
 if (Page_ClientValidate(valgroup)) {
//   alert('it is valid');
   return true;
 }
 else {
 //  alert('No valid');
   return false;
 }
```

How to you access the ValidationGroup property of the button?

**UPDATE**
Playing around with different jquery methods, this is what i am found...
I can get the ID of the sending button using this:

```
function Validate(ClientID)
{
    var val = $(ClientID).attr('id');
    alert(val); //this returns the id of the button (mggvAddButton)

    //This returns the DropDown list id, entries, etc.
    //This dropdown is beside the button.
    var val = $(ClientID).parent().parent().html();
    alert(val);

    //When I try to get the id of the dropdown, I get 'undefined.
    var val = $(ClientID).parent().parent().attr('id');
    alert(val);
}
```

Why can't it find the id of the dropdown?  It is in the html!

**UPDATE**

Adding the entire nested grid to better explain what I need to do...

```
<div id="div<%# Eval("GroupID") %>" style="display:none">
<asp:GridView ID="GroupMemberGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="GroupMemberGridView_RowDeleting" 
OnRowCommand="GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemberID">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberID") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="mggvLblMemberName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberName") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>               
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="mggvDDLMemberName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="chosen-single" data-placeholder="Choose member…">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqValueDDLMemberInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="mggvDDLMemberName" ValidationGroup="InsertMemberValidation" ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active Device(s)">                   
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="mggvLblActiveDevice" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveDevice").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>                   
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="mggvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"                                               Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Group Member?')" >
</asp:Button>
</ItemTemplate>                                     
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="mggvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Member" Width="90%" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="gridActionbutton" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="InsertMemberValidation" OnClientClick="return Validate(this);" >
</asp:Button>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

After some debugging, I have learned that the first nested grid and all of its controls can be easily accessed. However, the second nested grid has none of the control ids set.

The javascript function:

```
function Validate(sender)
{
    var e = document.getElementById("mggvDDLMemberName");
    var strSel = "The Value is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " and text is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    alert(strSel);
}
```

When I click the 'Add' button for the FIRST nested grid and select a value in the Dropdown, The above javascript function correctly displays the data.

When I click the 'Add button for the SECOND nested grid and select a value in the Dropdown. The above javascript function displays the Value as 0 and text is empty.

However, in BOTH cases the member is successfully added to the group and displayed in the list after the Add button is clicked.

So it appears that regardless of which 'Add' button is clicked, only the first nested grid data is read in this javascript function.  But in the code-behind, the Add event can correctly determine which nested grid to add the member to.

This is the GroupMember (nested grid) add row command:

```
protected void GroupMemberGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
       if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add"))
       {                 
          //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
          GridView tgvGroupMember = (GridView)sender;
          Control tFooterControls = CommonMethods.getFooterControls(tgvGroupMember);
          int tiMemberID = Convert.ToInt32((tFooterControls.FindControl("mggvDDLMemberName") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value);
          int tiGroupID = Convert.ToInt32((tgvGroupMember.Parent.FindControl("uggvLblGroupID") as Label).Text);

          //Insert into the database
          m_pagingClient.InsertGroupMember(tiGroupID, tiMemberID);

          //Rebind the grid with the new data
          populateGroupGrid();
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
      }
}
```

The method above determines which Member grid triggered the event and go from there.

I need to do the same on the client-side in the javascript function to validate the DDL entry.

Comment: If "dropdown is beside the button" then what you're looking for is jQuery siblings(), not parent()

Comment: That is what I don't understand...Dropdown is in the same row as the Add Button.  Yet, $(ClientID).parent().parent().html() displays all of the information in the Dropdown.  What I need is the 'imgdiv'GroupID' of the nested grid with contains the Add button that when clicked fires the Validate() function which is a parent.  But I have to learn what these functions return first.

Comment: What is the generated html? from the code above, it'd look like the you'd need to use `.prev()` instead of `.parent()` as (like @Neps said), the dropdown is a sibling and not a parent

Comment: OK.  I added the entire nested grid above and I will try to explain what I am trying to accomplish and what I am seeing in the javascript function.  I want to validate that the user selected an item in the dropdown list when they click the 'Add' button. Because it is a nested grid, all of the IDs are the same across the rows. So when a user clicks the 'Add' button, even if they select an item from the dropdown, the validator shows the error message.  I need to uniquely identify the validation group for each nested grid. I do this in the code-behind, see above.

Comment: In the javascript function, I need the name of the ValidationGroup that I set in the code-behind.  I can't see to figure out how to get this value that I set in the code-behind. I tried using sibling and that returns undefined.